# cursor fetch wrong records from mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
    >>> _cursor.execute("select * from bitter.test where id > 34")
    1L
    >>> _cursor.fetchall()
    ({'priority': 1L, 'default': 0, 'id': 35L, 'name': 'chinanet'},)
    >>> _cursor.execute("select * from bitter.test where id > 34")
    1L
    >>> _cursor.fetchall()
    ({'priority': 1L, 'default': 0, 'id': 35L, 'name': 'chinanet'},)
    >>>
```

the first time, i run cursor.execute and cursor.fetchall, i got the right result.

before the second time i run execute and fetchall

i insert data into mysql which id id 36, i also run commit command in mysql

but cursor.execute/fetchall counld only get the data before without new data

Comment: How did you do the second insert? From Python or the MySQL shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using InnoDB. This is default for an InnoDB transaction.

> REPEATABLE READ
>
> This is the default isolation level for InnoDB. For consistent reads,
>   there is an important difference from the READ COMMITTED isolation
>   level: All consistent reads within the same transaction read the
>   snapshot established by the first read. This convention means that if
>   you issue several plain (nonlocking) SELECT statements within the same
>   transaction, these SELECT statements are consistent also with respect
>   to each other. See Section 13.2.8.2, “Consistent Nonlocking Reads”.

I haven't tested yet but forcing MySQLdb to start a new transaction by issuing a `commit()` on the current connection or create a new connection might solve the issue.

Comment: thanks. You are right. after fetchall, run commit is ok. or SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED is ok too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got the result

```
import MySQLdb


conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'test', 'test', db='test')

cur = conn.cursor()

result = cur.execute("select * from users where id > 7")

print "RESULT :", result
print "DATA :", cur.fetchall()


cur.execute("insert into users(day) values('2012-03-15')")
conn.commit()

result = cur.execute("select * from users where id > 7")

print "RESULT :", result
print "DATA :", cur.fetchall()
```